# Google GeoChart (library Lavacharts) -> AddRow / AddRows not rendering any result on map despite array of values is created

Tags: arrays, laravel-5, google-visualization

**Issue:**

[Laravel GeoChart Library](http://lavacharts.com/#example-geo) to Render [Google Visualization](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery) -> AddRow / AddRows not rendering any result on map despite array of values is created.

**Controller Code (chart creation code)**

```
$countryIso = ['US','CA','BR']; 
foreach ($countryIso as $isocode) {
            $productDDP[$isocode] = $this->product->priceCalc($product = $product, $countryIso = $isocode);
        }
```

**View Results: using different variants of Code and giving errors:**

If I print the result of         `print_r($productDDP);`

it displays the following code:

```
Array
(
    [US] => 900
    [CA] => 1,276
    [BR] => 1,215
)
```

**I tried different approaches:**

**with             ->addRows(array($productDDP));**
"Invalid number of cells, must be less than or equal to the number of columns."

**with             ->addRow(array($productDDP));  or using             ->addRow([$productDDP]);**

Argument 3 passed to Khill\Lavacharts\DataTables\Cells\Cell::__construct() must be of the type array, string given

**with             ->addRows($productDDP);**

Argument 1 passed to Khill\Lavacharts\DataTables\DataTable::addRow() must be of the type array or null, string given

**with             ->addRow(array([$productDDP]))**

Render the chart but no value is set on the map.

Questions?

**- What I have to use for that kind of arrays?**

**- addRow or addRows?.**

**- In which format do we have to pass array data for addRow/s?**

Taking into consideration I passed all possible variants to addrow() I don't know if its an issue or a coding problem.

any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the array is in the wrong format
first, you're creating a single array, with key / value pairs

```
Array
(
    [US] => 900
    [CA] => 1,276
    [BR] => 1,215
)
```

each row should be an array with two values, no key value pairs

something like...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => US
            [1] => 900
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => CA
            [1] => 1276
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => BR
            [1] => 1215
        )

)
```

try building the arrays like this...

```
$countryIso = ['US','CA','BR'];
$productDDP = [];
foreach ($countryIso as $isocode) {
    $productDDP[] = array($isocode, $this->product->priceCalc($product = $product, $countryIso = $isocode));
}
```

then use `addRows`

```
addRows($productDDP);
```

Comment: you shed a big light on arrays to me. thank you! (SO says "you can award your bounty in 18hs", as soon they allow me I will award it) Best Regards!